# Facebook API on Unity Android app, login says it was "cancelled by the Player"?

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to follow the example on this :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/getting-started/android/

I'm using Unity 4.3.1f1

Using ADT : adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030

And using the Facebook API version 4.3.6 for unity.

I've followed the example properly, I created the app on [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com) and used the same display name and namespace as of the project. I also used the values that Facebook settings inside unity give me into the proper places (package name, class name and key hash), the key hash the api gives me is properly placed on the facebook page and using the command :

`"keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Rafael\.android\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64"`

Will also give me the same key hash so I believe everything is OK.

When building the apk, I choose the debug.keystore properly and put the proper password.

When running the InteractiveConsole demo, pressing Init works OK, but after pressing Login, it asks for permissions, I press OK and the login doesn't work, it says **it was cancelled by the Player**, login simply doesn't work and don't tell me why, any ideas ?

Comment: yes on mine too :/ Very weird. Thanks for noticing this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So answering my own question, turns out the key hash was wrong, I modified the facebook API file AndroidFacebook.cs and made it log whatever key hash it was using by changing this method :

```
public void OnLoginComplete(string message) 
{ 
   ... 
   if (parameters.ContainsKey("key_hash")) 
   { 
       keyHash = (string)parameters["key_hash"]; 
       Debug.Log("proper keyhash : " + keyHash); 
   } 
   ... 
 }
```

And the logged keyhash was different from what every other method was giving me, including the API own informed key, I added the proper key to the facebook page and everything is OK now.

Comment: @Rafael F.
How could you copy the logged hash as you were running the app on a real device?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

1. Get the fingerprint SHA1 (keytool -printcert -file CERT.RSA)
2. Copy the SHA1 HEX and convert that code to Base 64 (http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php)
3. You should copy the fingerprint in base 64 in the Android key hashes on your facebook app configuration.

That was all and it worked perfectly!